# Using API Endpoint to Scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[This](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwNyTEOgCAMBdDbdMbB8W_ewDibipU0sWAKIXp7Wd7yzDGRaUYg4xdzCBQ_bCvFwULP2HShs6s0vqkccG6aU925i3MSKjilRqow_QHEdBoL) website freezes after I load a few thousand results by using selenium to scroll automatically. Is there a way to use an API endpoint to scrape the (1) names of wines with their (2) ratings, (3) prices and(4) type of grape used? Thank you!

The below code only gets wines those 4 criteria but only from **one** country...is there a way to adapt it to return the grapes of type 131 (the code for a grape type called 'bobal') from **all** countries?

```
import requests
import math
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
s.get('https://www.vivino.com/', headers=headers)

cookies = s.cookies.get_dict()

cookieStr = ''
for k,v in cookies.items():
    cookieStr += k+'='+v+';'

url = 'https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore'
payload = {
'grape_ids[]':'131',
'grape_filter': 'varietal',
'min_rating': '1',
'order_by': 'discount_percent',
'order': 'desc',
'page': '1',
'per_page': '100',
'price_range_max': '40',
'price_range_min': '5'}

headers.update({'cookie':cookieStr})

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['explore_vintage']['records_matched'] / 100)

rows = []
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    if page != 1:
        payload.update({'page':page})
        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
    for each in jsonData['explore_vintage']['records']:
        name = each['vintage']['name']
        rating =  each['vintage']['statistics']['ratings_average']
        price = each['price']['amount']
        
        row = {'name':name, 'rating':rating, 'price':price}
        rows.append(row)
    print('Aquired page: %s' %page)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if I figured it out. But this returns 856 wines

```
import requests
import math
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
url = 'https://www.vivino.com/'

# Get Cache key to get country codes and type of wines
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script', text = re.compile('var vivinoCacheKey'))
vivinoCacheKey = str(script).split('vivinoCacheKey = ')[-1].split(';')[0].replace("'",'').strip()

# Get countries
api_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/api/countries'
payload = {
    'cache_key':vivinoCacheKey}
countryData = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()['countries']


rows = []
# Iterate through countries and wine types
api_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore'
for country in countryData:
    payload = {
    "country_code": country['code'].upper(),
    "currency_code":country['currency']['code'],
    'grape_ids[]':'131',
    "grape_filter":"varietal",
    "min_rating":"1",
    "order_by":"ratings_count",
    "order":"desc",
    "page": '1',
    "price_range_max":"1000",
    "price_range_min":"1"}

    try:
        jsonData = requests.get(api_url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
        total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['explore_vintage']['records_matched'] / 100)
        #print('%s' %(country['code'].upper()))
        
        for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
            if page != 1:   
                payload.update({'page':page})
            jsonData = requests.get(api_url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
            for each in jsonData['explore_vintage']['records']:
                name = each['vintage']['name']
                rating =  each['vintage']['statistics']['ratings_average']
                price = each['price']['amount']
                
                row = {'name':name, 'rating':rating, 'price':price}
                rows.append(row)
            print('Aquired page: %s - %s ' %(country['code'].upper(), page))
    except:
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                                              name  rating   price
0                 Mustiguillo Finca Terrerazo 2017     4.2   30.83
1              Beso de Rechenna Bobal Crianza 2016     3.6   10.16
2       Bruno Murciano Cambio de Tercio Bobal 2019     3.8   12.70
3                  Mustiguillo Quincha Corral 2016     4.4  106.35
4     Finca Sandoval Signo Bobal de Manchuela 2008     3.7   48.91
..                                             ...     ...     ...
851               Mustiguillo Finca Terrerazo 2016     4.1   20.88
852                              Pasión Bobal 2017     3.8   12.00
853  Chozas Carrascal Las 2 Ces Barrica Tinto 2012     3.3    8.00
854               Mustiguillo Finca Terrerazo 2017     4.2   20.66
855                           De Moya Justina 2018     3.9    6.48

[856 rows x 3 columns]
```

Another option here, for each time you select a country in the list, a new session cookie is created. I can get the initial one, but seems like th eonly way to get the specific one one you select a country is by simulating that selection with Selenium, and then getting that cookie. The other thing to now the website is designed to not give prices if you put the minimum price at 0. Don't know why they do that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import time
import math
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.vivino.com/explore"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

# If Cookie Notice pop up, then click on OK
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "cookieNotice")]').size != 0:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "cookieNotice")]//button').click()

# Slect Dropdown menu
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "simpleLabel__selectedKey")]').click()

# Click on United States and wait for page to render
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-value='US']").click()
time.sleep(5)

cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookieStr = ''
for each in cookies_list:
    cookieStr += each['name'] + '=' + each['value'] + ';'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
           'cookie':cookieStr}
rows = []
# Iterate through countries and wine types
api_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore'
payload = {
    "country_code": 'US',
    "currency_code": 'USD',
    'grape_ids[]':'131',
    "grape_filter":"varietal",
    "min_rating":"1",
    "order_by":"ratings_count",
    "order":"desc",
    "page": '1',
    "price_range_max":"1000",
    "price_range_min":"1"}

jsonData = requests.get(api_url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['explore_vintage']['records_matched'] / 100)
        
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    if page != 1:   
        payload.update({'page':page})
    jsonData = requests.get(api_url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
    for each in jsonData['explore_vintage']['records']:
        name = each['vintage']['name']
        rating =  each['vintage']['statistics']['ratings_average']
        try:
            price = each['price']['amount']
        except:
            price = None
        
        row = {'name':name, 'rating':rating, 'price':price}
        rows.append(row)
    print('Aquired page %s of %s ' %(page, total_pages))


df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: Hmmm. Ya could be. Man this site is killing me. I feel determined to crack it though.

Comment: I wonder, if you set currency code to usd, does it just then retrun all as us dollars? `"currency_code":'USD',`

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszVQy02ssDU0NjBQS660dQpSSwYSPmoFtoZq6Wm2ZYlFmakliTlq-Um2RYklmXnpxfGJZalFiempavm2KanFyQBt5RjT) in this link, you can see 546349 wines, you can do your requests using time.sleep for each country and you reload your requests with another
param:
Alemanha
Argentina
Austrália
Chile
Espanha
Estados Unidos
França
Itália
Portugal
Áustria

```
time.sleep(2.4)
```